# Prolog "," operator not working as intended?

Tags: prolog

I'm super unfamiliar with prolog but I need it for a school project. So, if I use unclear language or incorrect terms, please be understanding. My trouble is that my code is not working how I intended it at all. Here is a bit of my code in the knowledge base:

```
output(mn,hp,hp,hp). 
output(hn,mn,hp,lp).
output(ln,hp,mp,hp).
input(lp,mp,mp,lp):-output(hn,mn,hp,lp).
```

And here is my query:

```
?- input(X,mp,mp,lp),output(hn,mn,hp,lp).
```

I would expect it to return `X = lp`, as the if-then sentence in the knowledgebase states. However, it returns `X=hp`, `X=mp`, and `X=lp`, which is not what I intended.
I used "trace" to see how it reasoned, and I saw that it called for other outputs. I thought the "," operator meant "and", so it would only look for the output with the values (hn,mn,hp,lp). How can I get my code to only look for if-then sentences with the correct output values? Do I have an incorrect understanding of the "," operator or is the problem due to my knowledge base?

---

EDIT: Here is the link to my code in SWISH: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/i%20wanna%20bash%20my%20head%20in.pl#&togetherjs=AQ4zzkAQk4

---

EDIT 2: My aim with this project is the following:  I'm trying to explain a fuzzy cognitive map with this program. I want the program to determine the values of missing input concepts given the output concepts. So, I need the program to look for the clause with the correct values in output(), and then determine the values inside the relevant input().

Comment: Since you are added the [swi-prolog-for-sharing] tag, are you doing this in SWISH? Could you link to your program? I reconstructed it at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/QlAbitSc.pl and it behaves as you expect. I don't see the multiple incorrect answers that you are seeing.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Hi, thanks for answering! I am indeed doing this in SWISH. Here is the link, hope it works. https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/i%20wanna%20bash%20my%20head%20in.pl#&togetherjs=AQ4zzkAQk4
I think me having loads of if-then sentences is the problem, but I can't be certain.

Comment: When I run the ***code in your question*** I do get `X = lp.` as a result. Please include a [mcve] of your problem in your question - do not link to off to external sites please.

Answer (score 2):

With the whole program (88 lines):

```
?- output(hn,mn,hp,lp).
true.
```

So this can be completely disregarded in your query - it's **true** no matter what (constants only) and has no further effect.

Then what counts is:

```
?- input(X,mp,mp,lp).
X = mp ;
X = lp ;
X = hp ;
false.
```

No need for Prolog. Use text search to confirm that:

```
$ grep "mp,mp,lp" proggy.pl

input(mp,mp,mp,lp):-output(mn,hp,hp,hp).
input(mp,mp,lp,hp):-output(hn,lp,hp,hp).
input(mp,mp,lp,mp):-output(hn,mp,hp,hp).
input(lp,mp,mp,lp):-output(hn,mn,hp,lp).%this one is a pain in my ass
input(hp,mp,mp,lp):-output(ln,hp,mp,hp).
input(mp,mp,lp,lp):-output(ln,hp,mp,hp).
```

of the above, these three lines

```
input(mp,mp,mp,lp):-output(mn,hp,hp,hp).
input(lp,mp,mp,lp):-output(hn,mn,hp,lp).%this one is a pain in my ass
input(hp,mp,mp,lp):-output(ln,hp,mp,hp).
      <-><------> 
       X   MATCH
```

will match the query: 3 results with `X` from `mn,hn,ln`.

Working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a solution. Unfortunately, I don't think this works for my purposes, which I definitely should have included in my original question. I'm trying to explain a fuzzy cognitive map with this program. I want the program to determine the values of missing input concepts given the output concepts.  So, I need the program to look for the clause with the correct values in output(), and then determine the values inside the relevant input(). I will still consider your solution though, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler query:

```
?- input(X,mp,mp,lp).
```

This succeeds three times:

```
X = mp ;
X = lp ;
X = hp ;
false.
```

I assume you understand why this is: There are several matching clauses for `input` with different values for `X` and with bodies that succeed.

Now, you are right that `,` is conjunction, and that in general a goal `A, B` can succeed less often than `A` or `B` individually, but never more often. `A` and `B` typically constrain each other. But, very importantly: **If `A` and `B` do not share any variables, then they are independent.** In this case, the sequence of answers will be the Cartesian product of the answers for `A` and the answers for `B`. If `A` alone succeeds N times and `B` alone succeeds M times, then `A, B` without a shared variable will succeed N * M times.

You can only expect to see fewer solutions for a query of the form `?- input(X,mp,mp,lp), OtherGoal.` if `OtherGoal` also contains an occurrence of `X`. In your query this is not the case. The first conjunct succeeds three times, the second succeeds once, so overall you have 3 * 1 = 3 successes, as you observed.

So the question is: What are you trying to express with your query? You cannot express something like "give me solutions for `input`, but only by applying certain clauses of `output`".

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! My overall aim with this code is making an explanation mechanism for fuzzy cognitive maps. Given the expected values of output concepts and the values of some input concepts, I want the program to determine the values of the remaining input concepts. I tried going off the bit of code that the professor provided, and it works when there are few rules, but it also gives wrong answers when there is a lot. Thank you for your explanation though, I now understand why my query is not working for me.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Maybe what you want is to store rules of the form `output_input(output(hn,mn,hp,lp), input(lp,mp,mp,lp)).`, and then you can query this with a given output and partial input as `?- output_input(output(hn,mn,hp,lp), input(X,mp,mp,lp)).` and get `X = lp`.

Comment: @been I think you should ask a separate question about that. But you can take a look at the library me and my colleagues recently developed and maybe RCGA algorithm applies to your problem.

Article about the library is available here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12749v1


The package can be installed via pip
https://pypi.org/project/fcmpy/


Git repo
https://github.com/SamvelMK/FCMpy


cheers!